# Import data from another class python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter, parent

I need to access the temperature variable from Monitor Class and print on Graph Class. How can I do that? Please see code below which should compile.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import time

class ScientificPumpGui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MonitorPage, GraphPage):
            frame = F(self.container)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.show_frame(MonitorPage)

        self.create_buttons()
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
    def exit_app(self):
        exit()
    def create_buttons(self):
        main_b_height = 2
        main_b_width = 20
        page_button_pady = 10
        self.page_button_main_toolbar = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1)
        self.page_button_main_toolbar.pack(side=TOP, anchor=CENTER, fill=X)
        self.page_button_toolbar = tk.Frame(self.page_button_main_toolbar, borderwidth=1)
        self.page_button_toolbar.pack(side=TOP, anchor=CENTER)

        self.monitor_page_button = Button(self.page_button_toolbar, text="Monitor Page", width=main_b_width, height=main_b_height, command=lambda: self.show_frame(MonitorPage))
        self.monitor_page_button.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER, pady=page_button_pady)
        self.graph_page_button = Button(self.page_button_toolbar, text="Graph Page", width=main_b_width, height=main_b_height, command=lambda: self.show_frame(GraphPage))
        self.graph_page_button.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER, pady=page_button_pady)
        self.exit_app_button = Button(self.page_button_toolbar, text="Exit App", width=main_b_width, height=main_b_height, command=lambda: ScientificPumpGui.exit_app(0))
        self.exit_app_button.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=CENTER, pady=page_button_pady)


class MonitorPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.monitor_data_counter = 0

        self.page_label = tk.Label(self, text="Monitor Page")
        self.page_label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
    def value_function(self):
        self.temperature = 100

class GraphPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!")
        label.pack(pady=5, padx=10)

app = ScientificPumpGui()
app.mainloop()
```

When I tried to read temperature using:

```
monitor_page=MonitorPage(ScientificPumpGui())
print(str(monitor_page.temperature))
monitor_page.mainloop()
```

The error I get is:

> AttributeError: 'MonitorPage' object has no attribute 'temperature'

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because the member `temperature` is initialized in `value_function` method, which is not getting called.

As you didn't called to this method, the member `temperature` is not initialized and therefore you get the error.

In order to prevent this error, you should define the member `temperature` in your `__init__` method with a default value.

You also can fix it by calling to the `value_function` method in order to initialize the member `temperature`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MonitorPage` class does not declare`temperature` in the constructor function, but in `value_function`.

You can either declare `temperature` inside `__init__` function, or call `value_function` before reading `temperature`.

Comment: Thank you. Now the error is gone. How can I effectively access temperature from graph class?